# Video playing fine with ffplay, but not with vlc

Tags: video, ffmpeg, vlc-media-player

I'm trying to play a high definition video with vlc but it's really laggy and sometimes in between, the screen becomes almost 70% green. I'm able to play the same file with no problems using ffmpeg with the ffplay command so I think my hardware can handle it. Is there any way I can tweak my vlc settings to play it without problems on vlc.

The file's name includes  1080p.6ch.x265.10bit.[S-Less] if that helps. Thanks.

Comment: What version of VLC are you using? Latest seems to support x265 better. Also try PotPlayer. What happens when you try to play with PotPlayer. VLC 2.0 didn't do a great job of playing x265 but latest version seems to do better.

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser. As you already may suspect, the root cause of what you observe may be related to player software deploying hardware acceleration or not. In this regard, the file name is pretty irrelevant when in doubt although it might give a clue if it's correct. On the other hand, operating system, graphics card, graphics card driver, and VLC version may play a role here. Also, there are other good players out there which can do a better job, so do you really need to "fix" this".

Comment: I'm using vlc 2.2.1 on Ubuntu 14.04 and I have Intel Corporation Broadwell-U Integrated Graphics (rev 08) installed.

Answer (score 0):

Some recent VLC versions are known to have various decoding problems with certain formats. Try using an older version and it should function correctly. Just a few months back I had to roll-back from the updated version because it was causing similar issues. It's best to keep some older versions at hand, just in case.